# Route conversion for map.resources in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, resources

Currently, I have:

```
  map.resources :users do |user|
    user.resources :blogs
  end
```

How do I turn this into a match or resources in rails 3+?

My attempt would be:

```
resources :users do
  user.resources :blogs
end
```

I got most of my information on route changes from [here](http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-routing-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :users do
  resources :blogs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have `|user|` in the Rails 3 block, you cannot refer to it. In addition, you shouldn't need to:

```
resources :users do
  resources :blogs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) explains this. You should be able to use

```
resources :users do
  resources :blogs
end
```

Comment: I already read this and I have no idea how I missed the magazine/ads bit.